# can't get forward declaration to work in c++

Tags: c++, g++

I'm learning **C++**, using **g++ (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04) 7.4.0**

I have the following code :

- main.cpp :

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void log(std::string message);

int main() {
    log("HI");
}
```

- log.cpp :

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void log(std::string message) 
{
    std::cout << message << std::endl;
}
```

When i compile and run, i get the following error :

```
/tmp/ccYckYXk.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x43): undefined reference to `log(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can i please know what's wrong with my code ?

Comment: What's your compiler command line?

Comment: Do you compile `log.cpp` then link against it?

Comment: @Etienne ^ More specifically what's your linker command

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm fairly sure he doesn't compile and link separately, but yes, that's what I meant ;)

Comment: You need  `#include "log.h"` in each of the files. You need a log.h file and you need to compile with `g++ main.cpp log.cpp`

Comment: This article talks about what you are asking https://www.cs.fsu.edu/~myers/c++/notes/compilation.html